# Return two (or more) properties as a table with a single PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell command which returns all sorts of properties about disk drives attached to the system:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -like "\\?\*"}
```

I'm only interested in the `DriveLetter` and `DeviceID` properties and would like them to be returned in a table something like this:

```
DriveLetter    DeviceID
C:             \\?\Volume{5b982fce-d9e5-11e1-9c28-806e6f6e6963}\
D:             \\?\Volume{e9820c98-d688-11e1-a45f-001e673f1fc5}\
```

I know that I can surround my original command and use the dot operator to return one of my properties at a time:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -like "\\?\*"}).DriveLetter
```

Which in return produces:

```
C:
D:
```

But I don't know how to write a single statement that will return two (or more) properties as a table.  **If it's not possible to accomplish this with a single statement, what am I to do in order to produce the desired table output?**

I have searched Google for an answer but because I'm pretty new to PowerShell I probably am not phrasing my search terms correctly and thus not getting what I imagine is the simple answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -like "\\?\*"} | Select-Object -Property DriveLetter,DeviceID
```

Use `Get-Help Select-Object -Detailed` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Just format the output using the Format-Table cmdlet:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | 
Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -like "\\?\*"} | 
Format-Table DriveLetter,DeviceID
```

Generates output:

```
DriveLetter                                                            DeviceID                                                              
-----------                                                            --------                                                              
C:                                                                     \\?\Volume{118e4062-2eba-4f35-9b1b-015c3c1087dc}\                     
                                                                       \\?\Volume{e2a184aa-dac8-4196-80c6-fd8c7662e377}\                     
                                                                       \\?\Volume{33697e48-1197-464c-8553-cef00429e5a4}\
```

Make sure you understand how the formatting cmdlets (ft, fl etc) integrates with the objects on the pipeline.